# Why does not the optical fiber break?

Tags: classical-mechanics, optics, material-science, fiber-optics

Glass is a very fragile object. So why does not the optical fiber break? Everytime I take them, I am worried about this problem.

Comment: Glass with flaws is very brittle. The way optical fibers are drawn, and the surfaces treated, results in very few 'critical' flaws, so the probability of failure is actually quite low when used within the specs. As a related example, your classic Pyrex measuring cups are pretty darned rugged, whether pouring in boiling liquids, or dropping them on the counter - they don't shatter.

Comment: "Glass" is a generic term.  Optical fibers, eyeglasses, ceramics, and many other common items are glass.